# How can I get the header text at the top of the page in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing a page with local links in it. And for example this is a "team Name" local link when I click on it the page scrolls to the team Name header, when i get header `driver.findElements(By.xpath(//h1 || //h2 || h3).getText()` this code give to me first header element text but I want to get the text of the header that I clicked on and that appears at the top of the page at that moment. And Sometimes these local links lead to another header of another documentation. I want to be able to get the header here with the same code. Can you help?

```
 List<WebElement> links = seleniumHelper.getWebElementList(contextNavigateLinks);
            for (int j = 0; j < links.size(); j++){

                String expectedHeader = links.get(j).getAttribute("href").split("#")[1];
                System.out.println(expectedHeader);
                waitHelper.waitUntilElementIsInVisiableWithLocator(contextNavigateLinks, 30);
                seleniumHelper.forceClickToElement(links.get(j));
                String actualHeader = seleniumHelper.getTextWithBy(docsPageHeaders);
                seleniumHelper.assertValueWithString(actualHeader, seleniumHelper.castAString(expectedHeader));
            }
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page and your code?

Comment: Can you share HTML code for the header ?

Comment: Hi @Prophet and @cruisepandey this page link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links#specifications and i added my code in my question. `<h2 id="specifications"><a href="#specifications" title="Permalink to Specifications">Specifications</a></h2>`